# Print Incremental List items Javascript

Tags: javascript

This is a pure JavaScript question no jQuery please.

Trying to make a JavaScript Dartboard score keeper. Running into an issue of printing an incremental list. When you click a part of the dartboard would like to calculate throws 1, 2, and 3. The problem is I would like to print off those throws in incremental list format.

**HTML:**

```
<button class="score-section" data-value="20" data-multiplier="1">20</button>

<ul id="dartTotals">
  <li>Throw 1: {total}</li>
  <li>Throw 2: {total}</li>
  <li>Throw 3: {total}</li>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
document.body.onclick = function(e){
  e = e.target;
  if (e.className && e.className.indexOf('score-section') != -1) {
    var i = 0;
      (function increment(){
        document.getElementById('dartTotals').innerHTML += "<li> Throw " + ++i + ": " + " total </li>";
    }());
  }
}
```

The only thing I've been able to do is add 1 to `i` and just keep printing that off with out incrementing `i`. Or run a for loop and print off the list but it does it 3 at a time. Could someone assist in helping to show how I can go about making this incremental list with each click? Thanks in advance.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/wfuller/75a0sv07/2/)

**Update:**

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wfuller/75a0sv07/3/)

On body click the function was getting reset. Moved `var i`, now called `dartThrow` out of the function scope and is working as expected.

```
var dartThrow = 0;
document.body.onclick = function(e) {
  e = e.target;
  if (e.className && e.className.indexOf('score-section') != -1) {

    (function increment() {
      document.getElementById('dartTotals').innerHTML += "<li> Throw " + ++dartThrow + ": " + " total </li>";
    }());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting $i to 0 on every click and then increment that value. Just do a variable outside your functions scope and then it should increment properly everytime with the code you already do have. You'll just need a reset when $i reaches your total throw count that you want.

Comment: Duh, thanks for catching that :). Moved the variable outside the function scope and is working as expected. Updated the question with the answer and updated Fiddle and will accept your answer as soon as allowable.